# Using dropbox chooser to import pdf in ipad app

Tags: ios, pdf, ios6, dropbox, dropbox-api

Hello i'm building a iPad app in which i want to use dropbox to get my pdf files in my application. Now i've tried the dropbox sdk but didn't get it working. I've seen they have a special dropbox chooser but only in web. The basic idea is to get a chooser in which i can chose the pdf which i want to read in my custom ipad reader. My question is if anybody has already done this before or if anybody have some suggestions where i can start?

Comment: You have to integrate the Dropbox SDK into your app and write all of your own code to connect the user to their account, query their files, and present the list to the user for selection. The SDK comes with a sample that does much of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you dont need any special chooser module. Dropbox API is very rich in terms of selecting files with its types. Use this code

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata 
{
    NSMutableArray *pathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (DBMetadata *child in metadata.contents) {
        if (!child.isDirectory) {
            NSString *fileExtension = [[child.filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
            if ([fileExtension compare:@"pdf" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
             [pathArray addObject:child];
             }
        }
        else {
            [pathArray addObject:child];
        }
    }
}
```

This pathArray contains the list of PDF files only. Check it out and let me know if you are not getting anything. Have a Happy Coding.!! Cheers.!!